# Custom HTTP headers with Google Cloud CDN and Bucket backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, content-security-policy, google-cloud-cdn

How can I send custom HTTP headers with a bucket backend for Cloud CDN without the `x-goog-meta-` prefix?

In particular, I'm trying to send a `Content-Security-Policy` header, which turns into `x-goog-meta-Content-Security-Policy` and thus is ignored by the browser.

**Screenshot: Google Storage/ Bucket Meta data UI**

[image: Screenshot: Google Storage/ Bucket Meta data UI]

**Screenshot: Response headers**

[image: Screenshot: Response headers]

Comment: Yes those headers are added when working with custom metadata. It is explained in these articles [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#custom-metadata) and [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogmeta). I am doing some research to see if I can find a useful workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment setting up that header is not possible. There is an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36427250)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add CSP header to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500153/add-csp-header-to-google-cloud-storage)