# How to set X-Frame-Options for file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

After getting information about X-Frame-Options header, I want apply it to our scripts loaded from Google Cloud Storage via load balancer.
Files uploaded using `@google-cloud/storage`  npm package for nodejs.
This upload options snippet gives unexpected results:

```
     let requiredOptions = {
        resumable : false,
        predefinedAcl: 'publicread',
        metadata: {
            contentType: 'text/javascript',
            cacheControl: 'public, max-age=35920000, no-transform',
            contentEncoding: 'gzip',
            metadata: {
                ['X-Frame-Options']: 'sameorigin'
            }
        }
    };
```

Problem: the resulting headers contain the `x-goog-meta-x-frame-options: sameorigin` instead of expected `x-frame-options: sameorigin`.

When I tried to use

```
     let requiredOptions = {
        resumable : false,
        predefinedAcl: 'publicread',
        metadata: {
            contentType: 'text/javascript',
            cacheControl: 'public, max-age=35920000, no-transform',
            contentEncoding: 'gzip',
            ['X-Frame-Options']: 'sameorigin'
        }
    };
```

The `X-Frame-Options` did not included at all.
How to add advanced header to uploaded file metadata in a way that resulting header name will not start from `x-goog-meta-` prefix?

Comment: I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853564/custom-http-headers-with-google-cloud-cdn-and-bucket-backend) that seems to be related with your issue. As is specified in the comments, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36427250) opened, that you can comment and star it in order to follow the process.

Comment: Thanks! I stared that feature request