# Add CSP header to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, content-security-policy

I'm serving a SPA (Vue-app) from a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
And I'm trying to **configure Google Cloud Storage bucket to add a CSP Response header**. (`Content-Security-Policy: default ...`)

I've tried the following, but without success:

#### 1. Adding header with `gsutil`

Running the following:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Security-Policy:${CSP}" gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/index.html
```

But this returns the following response:

```
CommandException: Invalid or disallowed header (Content-Security-Policy).
Only these fields (plus x-goog-meta-* fields) can be set or unset:
[u'cache-control', u'content-disposition', u'content-encoding', u'content-language', u'content-type']
```

It seems this header is not standardly allowed to add.

#### 2. Adding Custom header with prefix with `gsutil`

I then proceeded to follow their advice and prepend `x-goog-meta-*` in the hopes they convert it back to `Content-Security-Policy` themselves. Running the following:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "x-goog-meta-Content-Security-Policy:${CSP}" gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/index.html
```

..gives the following response:

```
Setting metadata on gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/index.html...
/ [1 objects]                                                                   
Operation completed over 1 objects.
```

So this works. But upon checking the response headers, they did not alter it to `Content-Security-Policy` header:
[image]

So now I'm a bit clueless how to enable this CSP-header for Google Storage buckets.
What am I missing? Or is this simply not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sadly it's not possible at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment Google Cloud Storage doesn’t admit customs headers, just the [headers included in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers).

There is a public feature request for this that you can follow in [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36427250).

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported on bucket level, but it is supported at Load Balancer level, check the official [Cloud Storage Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers#response-options-storage)

Comment: That's legacy docs now, [latest one here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers-global)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following tag within the `<head>` tag of your the SPA to enable `Content-Security-Policy`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:">
```

For further information please see the following:

[Mozilla: The Document-level Metadata element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)

[Mozilla: Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)